# How can I read JPEG EXIF orientation tags in a MS Word macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word, windows-10, jpeg, exif

I have a Word macro that opens all the JPEGs in a particular folder, and inserts them into the document. The problem is the orientation. My macro reads the width vs. length to determine the orientation. But Word inserts the image according to the EXIF orientation tag, and Windows 10 rotates by the EXIF orientation tag. That means I have no real way of controlling the rotation of the image in the document.

How can a Word macro read the EXIF orientation tag of a JPEG?

Comment: I'm puzzled why this is marked as a duplicate. I see nothing in the linked question that answers this one. It shows the direction and that their probably is an answer but does not give the answer.

Comment: Have pretty much the same problem. Don't know why this was marked duplicate either. Posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51400088/excel-vba-image-exif-orientation

Comment: I can't see how to undo my close-as-dup but I did change the link to something which looks more promising...

Comment: ...nope - that's the same code different link.  Sorry - messed that up.

Comment: @pnuts - OK re-opened....