# Excel VBA Image EXIF Orientation

Tags: vba, image, excel, image-scaling

Made this macro that inserts images from the active directory into an excel spreadsheet and scales it down to fit in the cell. It works pretty well except for images that come from a source were their orientation/rotation is defined in the EXIF data. So in:

- In Windows Explorer - Not rotated
- Window Picture viewer - Not rotated
- IE - Not Rotated
- Chrome - Rotated
- EXCEL - Rotated

It's all due to [some legacy issue](https://www.howtogeek.com/254830/why-your-photos-dont-always-appear-correctly-rotated/) from the camera that the image was taken from. Somebody post a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650664/how-can-i-read-jpeg-exif-orientation-tags-in-a-ms-word-macro?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it got labelled as a duplicate, incorrectly, and has been ignored since. I did find this [obscure post](https://forum.oberonplace.com/showthread.php?t=8076) were somebody linked an exif reader class, I tested it and it gave me the same `Orientation` value for all my images.

**The Problems**: the photo gets rotated properly (YAY!), but its **position** is 35-80 columns to the right (Boo!) and/or 200 rows down, and the scaling is off because it mixes the width and height fields (Boo! x2).

Here's my Code:

```
For Each oCell In oRange
        If Dir(sLocT & oCell.Text) <> "" And oCell.Value <> "" Then
        'Width and Height set to -1 to preserve original dimensions.
            Set oPicture = oSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=sLocT & oCell, LinktoFile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoTrue, Left:=oCell.Left + 10, Top:=oCell.Top + 10, Width:=-1, Height:=-1)

            oPicture.LockAspectRatio = True

        'Scales it down  
            oPicture.Height = 200
        'Adds a nice margin in the cell, useless             
            oCell.RowHeight = oPicture.Height + 20
            oCell.ColumnWidth = oPicture.Width / 4
        Else

            oCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
        End If
        Next oCell
```

Image dimensions can be variable from unknown sources (but I'm pretty sure we can blame Samsung on this one). Looking for a solution and/or an explanation without the need of a 3rd party application.

Here's a [sample of the images](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k2LeTxvpmCqT4rMGB0jWGX3YChdcDrqE/view?usp=sharing) to try out, the first image works properly, the others don't.

Comment: Can you provide links to set of images with different rotation?

Comment: Check this: [Rotate Shape Object in VBA](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/596910-rotate-object-vba.html)

Comment: @martin [Is this in any way related?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50634741/445425)  Note: as  Maciej commented, it would be nice if you added some sample pic's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check the rotation to see if you have to adjust height or Width (Top or Left)

Adjust your loop as follows:

```
For Each oCell In oRange
        If Dir(sloct & oCell.Text) <> "" And oCell.Value <> "" Then
          Set oPicture = osheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=sloct & oCell, LinktoFile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoTrue, Left:=oCell.Left + 10, Top:=oCell.Top + 10, Width:=-1, Height:=-1)

          With oPicture
                .LockAspectRatio = True
            If .Rotation = 0 Or .Rotation = 180 Then
                .Height = 200
                 oCell.RowHeight = .Height + 20
                 oCell.ColumnWidth = .Width / 4
                .Top = oCell.Top
                .Left = oCell.Left
            Else
                .Width = 200
                oCell.RowHeight = .Width + 20
                oCell.ColumnWidth = .Height / 4
                .Top = oCell.Top + ((.Width - .Height) / 2)
                .Left = oCell.Left - ((.Width - .Height) / 2)
            End If

           End With
        Else
            oCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
        End If
        Next oCell
```

Comment: + When adding picture in Excel, rotation from EXIF is already used in Excel, so you can act accordingly

Comment: In Excel 2013, when `.Rotation` is not available, check for `.ShapeRange.Rotation`

Comment: Nevertheless i still have a problem. For reproducing it, just choose a Top Left cell in the `B` column. When doing the correction `(W-H)/2`, the "Phantom" rotated margin blocks the picture, and a proper left displacement is not possible. Is there a way to fix this? By removing the EXIF rotation (i.e. [FastStone Viewer](https://superuser.com/questions/57317/editing-jpeg-exif-properties) ), the issue is circumvented